# To kill a cuckoo

Tags: knowledge

Now *these* are stories I'd like to hear !

> First born goes to Saturn
>
> Ducks go bomb stuff in winter
>
> Highness bequeathes his lands to imaginary sheep
>
> One for all, including a dog
>
> Clumsy girl goes into hiding
>
> Roaring parties in the pip-filled Big Apple
>
> Elves' disastrous self-government
>
> Jailbait esper

What are they ?

Comment: <knowledge> tag maybe necessary for finding all of them, but most people can probably find some.

Comment: Naturally, I "got" the title, but none of the text.... :P

Answer (score 8):

**Partial answer**

Taking a cue from Fillet's observation that

> one of the clues looks as if we're looking at a mashup of two books with titles that begin the same way

and (EDITED to add this)

> OP's clarification that some of the title-relationships are less specific than "begin the same way"

I tentatively propose:

*One for all, including a dog*

> The three musketeers / Three men in a boat

*Clumsy girl goes into hiding*

> Diary of a Wimpy Kid / Diary of Anne Frank

*Jailbait esper*

> Lolita / Matilda

Fillet's answer has solutions for *Elves' disastrous self-government* and *Roaring parties in the pip-filled Big Apple*, so still remaining are:

*First born goes to Saturn*
*Ducks go bomb stuff in winter*
*Highness bequeathes his lands to imaginary sheep*

[EDITED: Some stuff deleted because its only point was to help with an extraction step that OP has clarified isn't there.]

Further vague speculation:

> "Highness bequeaths his lands" sounds a bit like *King Lear*, though I think "Highness" is for princes and "Majesty" for kings.

Comment: Everything you said is pretty much correct (Well I had Bridget's Jones diary, but that's to taste). The puzzle is probably not as elaborate as you think : there is sadly no "final answer", and titles can be related by more fuzzy relationships than a common word.

Answer (score 6):

Elves' disastrous self-government

> Maybe a crossover between Lord of the Flies (disastrous self-government) and Lord of the Rings (Elves galore)? Lord of the flying Rings?

Roaring parties in the pip-filled Big Apple

> A crossover from Great Expecations (Pip is the protagonist) to The Great Gatsby (Parties in NY in the roaring twenties) - The Great Gatsby Expectations

Answer (score 1):

Imaginary sheep

> "The little prince" came to my mind. fits with "highness"...